# How do I do different things per macro value?

Tags: c, macros

```
#define TYPE char *

if TYPE is char *
  do A
if TYPE is int
  do B
```

Is there an example how to do such things?

Comment: Not with C macros, but you could use C++ magic for that (even without macros).

Comment: Is it ok to treat TYPE as just a string of characters?  That is, if TYPE was charptr where charptr is a typedef of char *, is it ok for that not to match the char * case?

Comment: The next version of the standard will have a construct that fills that gap, so-called generic selection with the `_Generic` keyword.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Thanks for the info! This lead me to wiki page on C1X...

Answer (score 2):

C preprocessor MACROS manipulate text, so are essentially typeless, so NO you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

You could associate another symbol with it:

```
#define TYPE char *
#define TYPE_IS_CHAR_STAR

#ifdef TYPE_IS_CHAR_STAR
...
#endif
```

You just need to keep them consistent manually.

Note that that's a dangerous macro; you should use a `typedef` instead.  With the macro:

```
TYPE x, y;
```

`x` is a pointer, but `y` isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a similar effect by defining another macro along with the type, and using `#ifdef` etc. with that other macro.  For example:

```
#define TYPE char *
#define TYPE_IS_PCHAR 1
```

...then later...

```
#ifdef TYPE_IS_PCHAR
   do A
#endif
#ifdef TYPE_IS_INT
   do B
#endif
```

It's not quite the same thing, but it still gets you there.

Answer (score 0):

Not easily. You could do something like:

```
#define TYPE_IS_CHARPTR
//#define TYPE_IS_INT

#ifdef TYPE_IS_CHARPTR
    do A
#endif
#ifdef TYPE_IS_INT
    do B
#endif
```

But you really should be trying to minimise your use of the preprocessor for tricky things (anything other than simple variables).

With enumerated constants and inline functions, there's little need for such uses nowadays.

Comment: Not only that,it seems `#ifdef ABGC2|| #ifdef DE` is also not possible ,right?

Comment: @JeRog `#if defined(ABGC2) || defined(DE)`

Answer (score 0):

It would work if you just used basic types (since they're just strings - see Mitch's answer).  But as soon as you try to use pointers, it won't work any more - the asterisk throws the preprocessor for a loop:

```
[holt@Michaela ~]$ gcc test.c
test.c:3:10: error: operator '*' has no right operand
```

But if you want do do different things based on different types, I'm going to have to recommend switching to C++ and using [templates](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/144-expression-parameters-and-template-specialization/) and [template specialization](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/146-partial-template-specialization/).  Reluctantly, since template syntax is incredibly ugly, but you should be able to do whatever you want.

Hope that helps!